# Can alkylboron amines undergo Suzuki reaction with bromobenzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

$$\ce{NH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-B(OR)2}$$

I don't know what the name of this compound is, but can the Suzuki reaction proceed under basic conditions with an aryl halide and a general palladium catalyst in the case of an alkylborane with a free amine attached to the end?

Comment: You may find useful these links for text formatting ( not to be applied to titles ):
 [notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [text + formula formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: Your structure will undoubtedly exist as a cyclic structure and possibly lose ROH.